Web Scraping com Python (site B3)
Estou tentando fazer um Web scraping do site da B3, mais especificamente da pagina: Taxas Referenciais
Mas está trazendo a tabela vazia. Como fazer para resolver e trazer todas as informações da tabela?
Abaixo segue o código em python utilizado
`Importando Bibliotecas
import requests from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import pandas as pd import pandas.tseries.offsets as ts import numpy as np import datetime
​import pandas as pd from pandas.tseries.offsets import BMonthBegin, CustomBusinessDay from pandas.tseries.holiday import AbstractHolidayCalendar, Holiday
Data da curva
Data = input('Digite a data:')
Web Scraping
url = 'https://www2.bmf.com.br/pages/portal/bmfbovespa/lumis/lum-taxas-referenciais-bmf-ptBR.asp'
params = {'dData': {Data}, 'slcTaxa': {'PRE'} }​response = requests.get(url, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
Dados_B3 = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
Dados_B3['DI x pré'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
Dados_B3.tail(100)`
⁴

1- Para evitar o bloqueio automático e restrições pelo sistema não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações a você concedidas na pergunta original. 2- Não faça a raspagem de sites que oferecem servidores dedicados a extração de dados brutos, use a API da B3.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
